# Prestashop adminpanel access issue

Tags: prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.7.3.3 version. I have a problem, i can not log in due to the error below.

How can i fix this problem?

Problem:

Found an error: country_module_list.xml dosyasında Couldn't find end of Start Tag badg line 1 .
Found an error: country_module_list.xml dosyasında Premature end of data in tag badges line 1 .
Found an error: country_module_list.xml dosyasında Premature end of data in tag module line 1 .
Found an error: country_module_list.xml dosyasında Premature end of data in tag modules line 1 .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file and clear cache and the check again.